# How to deploy a jquery-mobile web app to an Iphone store app

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile

I have built a Jquerymobile webapp , I want to take it a step further, build additional features and deploy it as an iphone app. I am confused on connecting these two dots. I looked at Phonegap and Titanium. Phonegap does not allows to register yet and Titanium seems like I have to code everything again using Titanium apps . Any ideas on how to bridge the gap of connecting iphone app and jquerymobile.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "Phonegap does not allows to register yet"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use phonegap for my iPhone apps and it works well. Phonegap Build will even encode the iPhone (and Android, Blackberry, etc) app for you so you don't have to use Xcode.

Phonegap download 0.9.6:  http://www.phonegap.com/download-thankyou

How to start an app using Xcode and Phonegap: http://www.phonegap.com/start

signup for Phonegap Build: https://build.phonegap.com/

Comment: Phonegap is the response I am getting from all and you are correct to point that out.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just take your already written JS code and use it as your source for a UIWebView? Those middle-ware platforms you mentioned have their own JS libraries you need to use, but if the code you already made will work as-is on an iPhone, dumping it into a UIWebView should be all you need to do.

Comment: Have never tried this . Can you point to some documentation or examples that can help with this. Thank you.